# Correct Outlook search modifier to find mail sent OR received by person?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

Is there a modifier to find any mails either sent to or received from a given contact?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use something from this [kb](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) like

```
from: "adolf garlic" OR to: "adolf garlic"
```

Not sure if you can combine it in a different structure

Comment: that only seems to return mails where they have somehow sent AND received it

Answer (score 0):

Open outlook and press Ctrl+E and then click on 'All Subfolders' tab.

[image]

Then enter the name of the particular contact in the search box.

Comment: No this doesn't work at all. Basically that returns any mail where the user's name appears. I am only interested in mails sent/received by that person

Comment: Right click the 'arrange by' tab just below the search box and then select to or from. And then enter the name in the search box.